# Azure bot service using On Premise database

Tags: azure-bot-service

We are trying to create a bot and want to use the skype for business or microsoft teams channel. The client has its own microsoft private cloud and is ok to use azure bot service ,howwver they want the data to reside in the exadata on premise database. Could you please let me know whats the best way of creating azure bot for skype that interacts with on premise database? Can we use hybrid connection manager ?

Comment: Good Questions, this is the real case, enterprise environment.

Comment: Hi eng soon cheah yes this is the enterprise datawarehouse .

Answer (score 0):

What data exactly are you referring to? [State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) storage? Something else? Is the bot application (App Service) running in the private cloud, or is that also running on-prem? (it can)

> Can we use hybrid connection manager ?

I'm not sure about that, but if you can get the bot App Service (or any app service) to be able to communicate with the database, then it all you have to do is implement the state storage interface.

Likely you would do that with [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#handling-state-in-middleware).  I would suggest reviewing [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) as well. While memory/azureblob/cosmosdb are the defacto (and preconfigured) options, you should be able to get it to work with other storage options and middleware as well.

Comment: Hi Dana..the bot service will run on cloud ..the bot we are trying to build will  have the backend database on premise...so any query that the user has will hit the database and the reply will be rendered on the the skype for business channel ..due to client policies we do not want to store /move  data to move to cloud(azure blob/cosmos) .. so what is the best way to have bot service communicate with on premise database ?

Comment: Use the middleware route then. Set up the bot App Service to connect to the database, then implement the state storage into that via middleware.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dana..but my query is the same what is the best way/architecture to set up bot service to connect to on premise database ?

Comment: That is somewhat of a [subjective question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and too general as well. Regardless, the bot is just an App Service application. As far as connection, there isn't anything different apart from implementing what exactly you want to store in the database (bot state, transcriptions, etc). I took a quick look and though it is old, I found [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/panditdeepak/access-on-premise-sql-server-database-from-azure-web-app-usi/). It does mention hybrid connection manger. Might be a good starting point.